# python googlefinance api getQuote breaks the passed StockSymbl into array of characters

Tags: python, api

When I use method getQuotes( ) from googlefinance0.7, it is breaking String into characters and running for each characters. so getQuote('PG') is churning output as getQuote('P') , '\n' ,  getQuote('G').

I must be doing something wrong ? 
Could not find API documentation for googpefinance0.7 either to see if other methods would provide an alternative.

Thanks. 
-PL

## code :

```
searchStrNameAry = np.array(['X' , 'PG'])

for item in searchStrNameAry: 
    print (item, "\n")
    print (json.dumps(getQuotes(item), indent=2))
```

## This outputs :

```
X 

[
  {
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Apr 26, 1:11PM EDT",
    "StockSymbol": "X",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "23.20",
    "Index": "NYSE",
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2017-04-26T13:11:50Z",
    "ID": "38983",
    "LastTradePrice": "23.20",
    "LastTradeTime": "1:11PM EDT"
  }
]
PG 

[
  {
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Apr 26, 1:11PM EDT",
    "StockSymbol": "P",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "10.94",
    "Index": "NYSE",
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2017-04-26T13:11:23Z",
    "ID": "4592563",
    "LastTradePrice": "10.94",
    "LastTradeTime": "1:11PM EDT"
  },
  {
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Apr 26, 1:10PM EDT",
    "StockSymbol": "G",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "24.66",
    "Index": "NYSE",
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2017-04-26T13:10:55Z",
    "ID": "716027",
    "LastTradePrice": "24.66",
    "LastTradeTime": "1:10PM EDT"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getQuotes()` take a `str` or an iterable, unfortunately because you have created a `numpy` array the type of `searchStrNameAry[0]` is `numpy.str_` which it is not expected, so is treated like an iterable.

Either explicitly ensure the `type` is `str`:

```
for item in searchStrNameAry: 
    print (item, "\n")
    print (json.dumps(getQuotes(str(item)), indent=2))
```

Or get all the quotes in one call:

```
print (json.dumps(getQuotes(searchStrNameAry), indent=2))
```